# Apache: keep track of non-404 errors (e.g., 403, 500, et al)

Tags: php, htaccess

In cpanel I always have the error log open ("This function will display the last 300 errors for your site.") which is nice for 404's but what about the rest?

I'm working on a few things in htaccess, such as this:

```
RedirectMatch 403 /(\$|\*)/?$
```

So now when I try any URL with a dollar-sign or an asterisk in it, bam, 403 forbidden; perfect.

So I refresh cpanel's error log page, and nothing. It seems to only care about 404's.

Incidentally, httpd.conf, which I cannot alter, is setup this way:

```
CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
```

The errors I'd like to know how to monitor are: 400, 401, 403, and 500.

Comment: Can you look at the log file another way? For example, can you download it or FTP it to your local computer? I do not think at this point your logging is in error. I would be downloading the raw access and error log files and checking them. I cannot yet imagine a hosting scenario where your errors appear in the common Apache logs and not the site logs. I am not familiar with CPanel and how it may set things up.

Comment: You can monitor all these in Google Webmaster Tools or are you wanting something server-side in real time?

Answer (score 1):

The Apache error log *does* track errors other than 404 errors.   In the case of 500 errors, it shows you any error output from your scripts.   cPanel must be hiding this information from you.

I usually filter the access logs to see a single line for each error page that occurs.   I tend to use the command line to tail and filter it like this:

```
tail -F /var/log/apache2/access_log | grep -E '" (404|403|500) '
```